# Android API Level is not shown Visual Studio 2013

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to create Xamarin Form according to this article.[An Introduction to Xamarin.Forms](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/)
But on vs 2013,it doesn't show the required Android API Level.Why's That ? It shows properly on project properties though ? :(

**VS 2013 Ultimate (debug)** :

[image]

On **project properties** it shows properly :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking at in the top image are the different emulators you have setup.

You can create more of these by starting **AVD Manager** (Android Virtual Device Manager) and creating your own device with the appropriate API level.

[image]

Comment: Without creating it I need to give it as API Level 19 .But it doesn't show on the above drop down ?

Comment: @Sampath: if you only have emulators at Level 10 and 12 then it doesn't make sense to create a project at level 19, does it? Your emulators won't be able to run your app.

Comment: Ok then why's it shown on project properties window ?

Comment: I don't think you're reading what I wrote. The top image shows your *emulators*. You show that you **only** have emulators for API levels 10 and 12. In the bottom image you show that you've set up your project as API level 19. You cannot execute a level 19 app on a level 12 emulator. What you need to do is create a new emulator in AVD that targets API level 19 which will then show up in your list.